# Extended Bottom Nav Bar like Microsoft Team in React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am using the Tab Bar library for the bottom nav bar but Nav bar shows a limited number of items in a bar like 3-4 items.

In my project, I have 15 items to show in the bottom tab bar. Hence we decided to show it as an extended bottom nav bar similar to the Microsoft team mobile app. Please have a look at the attached image.

**I am new in react js and tried multiple blog posts but could not find any solution for it. Please help me out.**

[image: Extended Nav bar]